# Open a file that has just been closed

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application that manipulates a text file.  The first half of my function reads the textfile, while the second half writes to (optionally) the same file.  Although I call `.close()` on the StreamReader object before opening the StreamWriter object, I still get a `IOException: The process cannot access the file "file.txt" because it is being used by another process.`

How do I force my program to release the file before continuing?

```
public static void manipulateFile(String fileIn, String fileOut,String obj)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileIn);
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //code to split up file into part1, part2, and part3[]
        }
        sr.Close();

        //Write the file
        if (fileOut != null)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileOut);
            sw.Write(part1 + part2);
            foreach (String s in part3)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(s);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show your code. That's the only way you can get relevant help to your particular scenario.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, did you call the `Dispose()` method, or wrap your `StreamReader` in a `using { }` block?  Disposing it might force the file to be freed up.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla, you should never call `Dispose` manually, you should always use `using` blocks when dealing with disposable resources.

Comment: @Darin I disagree that you should NEVER call it manually.  You shouldn't call it manually unless you have a good reason to.  For instance if you already have a try/catch block (say the file might not exist), no point in putting a `using` around that, just put `dispose` in the `finally`

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Why would that be? How would you release a resource in another context then? Such a general rule (i.e. to never call `Dispose` explicitly) makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: @Davy8, why writing a try/catch/finally when there's the using statement? It's soooo much more code.

Comment: @Darin: You realize that the using block just explodes out to a try..finally that calls dispose()?

Comment: @0xA3, if you always stick to the one of the fundamental rules which is always use `using` statements with when dealing with disposable resources you should never call the `Dispose` method manually. Calling the Dispose method manually means that you must handle the case of exceptions, etc,... meaning that you must write try/catch/finally which is soooo much more code when you have the `using` statement.

Comment: @Chris Lively, I absolutely realize this and I absolutely realize that this makes your code much more concise. I mean writing try/finally is much more code. Also it's kinda ugly. So if we all stick to the fundamental rule, questions like this one simply won't exist on StackOverflow and we all would be happy developers :-)

Comment: @Darin because you can't have a catch block in a using statement.  If you need to catch and handle an exception, there's no point in adding another level of nesting by either putting a try/catch inside or around a using statement.

Comment: @Davy8, `catch` blocks are ugly, they clutter your code and could be source for potential bugs of swallowing important information. In general I prefer to leave exceptions propagate and catch them in a global exception handler. If you write good code exceptions shouldn't happen and in the exceptional case they do, you catch them in a global exception handler, log them and inform the user that something terribly wrong happened.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: My point was that you can't always use `using` because you might not want to release the resource within the same method. A typical example would be Windows Forms controls (the forms designer handles that for you, but you might want to create and remove controls dynamically too).

Comment: @0xA3, in the case of Windows Forms you don't call the Dispose method manually neither which was my point: avoid calling this method manually.

Comment: @Darin IOExceptions need to be caught to be handled properly.  If a your program is reading a file from a network drive that got disconnected, it should inform the user that the file can't be accessed, and give some hint as to what to do (reconnect, try a different file).  It should definitely not crash the app.

Comment: @Davy8, who said something about crashing the application? I talked about a global exception handler where you would catch all unhandled exceptions and act accordingly.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: This is only true for the controls owned by the form, and only true if you don't want to remove controls dynamically at runtime. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106549/disposing-dynamically-created-controls

Comment: @Darin, WinForms was simply referenced as an example to illustrate how Dispose needs to be explicitly called when a class encapsulates a disposable object.  In this scenario, it may not be possible to use a using statement within the encapsulating class because the disposable object exists across method calls.  In this case, though, the encapsulating class most likely should also implement the IDisposable interface as well.

Comment: I agree that a try/catch is sometimes necessary, such as for logging.  You may need to log data that is only available from the context in which an exception occurred, therefore certain kinds of logging may not be possible with only a global exception handler.  However, I can't really disagree with Darin's point of view that one should always use a `using` block for disposable objects (at least when possible).  Using a `using` block doesn't prevent you from also including a try/catch if necessary.

Comment: @Darin how would a global handler have the context to know whether an exception was safe or not.  I'd argue that a global exception handler should never stop an app from crashing.  Logging the error, and possibly restarting it (say it's some service that needs to keep running) is fine.  If you don't need a catch block (i.e. there aren't any specific exceptions that you know are non-fatal) then `using` is definitely the way to go, however if you already have a try/catch, adding a `finally` and dispose is functionally identical and IMO cleaner than nesting `using` and `try/catch/finally`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as posted runs fine - I don't see the exception.

However calling `Close()` manually like that is a bad idea - if an exception is thrown your call to `Close()` might never be made. You should use a finally block, or better yet : a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileIn))
{
    // ...
}
```

But the actual problem you are experiencing might not be specifically with this method, but a general problem with forgetting to close files properly in `using` blocks. I suggest you go through all your code base and look for all the places in your code where you use `IDisposable` objects and check that you dispose them correctly *even when there could be exceptions*.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of `using` statements when dealing with disposable resources such as StreamReaders.

Comment: Turns out the file was being edited in another method and not closing.  Changing all my writers and readers to use the Using statement did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Getting read access to a file that's already opened elsewhere isn't usually difficult.  Most code would open a file for reading with FileShare.Read, allowing somebody else to read the file as well.  StreamReader does so for example.

Getting write access is an entirely different ball of wax.  That same FileShare.Read does *not* include FileShare.Write, allowing you to *write* the file while somebody else is reading it.  That's very troublesome, you're jerking the mat out from under that somebody else, suddenly providing entirely different data.

All you have to do is find out who that 'somebody else' might be.  SysInternals' Handles utility can tell you.  Hopefully it is your own program, you could do something about *that*.

Answer (score 0):

May sound like a stupid question, but are you sure you didn't edit the file with another application, which didn't release the file? I've had this situation before, mostly with Excel files where Excel didn't  completely unloading from memory (or me just being dumb enough not to close the other application sometimes). Might happen with whatever application you use for .txt files, if any. Just a suggestion.